# If $X$ follows a normal distribution, $X/\sigma$ follows a normal distribution??

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

If $X$ follows a normal distribution, $X/\sigma$ ($\sigma$ is the standard deviation) follows a normal distribution? I have tried to prove using the transformation formula but I can't.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(X \leq x)=\frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi} \sigma} \int_{-\infty} ^{x}  e^{-(t-m)^{2}/2\sigma^{2}} dt$ where $m=EX$. Hence $P(\frac X {\sigma} \leq x)=P(X \leq \sigma x)= \frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi} \sigma} \int_{-\infty} ^{\sigma x}  e^{-(t-m)^{2}/2\sigma^{2}} dt$. Put $y=\frac t \sigma$. We get $P(\frac X {\sigma}\leq x) =\frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi} } \int_{-\infty} ^{x} e^{-(y-\frac m {\sigma})^{2}/2} dy$. Hence $\frac X \sigma \sim N(\frac m \sigma,1)$.

Comment: Ok, I was stuck with that...Do you know if we can extend this result to any location-scale family...this is, if X-a (a: location parameter) and X/b (b: scale parameter) also follow the same distribution as X?I can´t see it in any book...

Comment: @LuisGimenoSotelo If $X \sim N(m,sigma^{2})$ then $aX+b \sim N(am+b, a^{2}\sigma^{2})$ and this is a special property of normal distribution. It is not always true for other distributions.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)).

Suppose $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$. Let $Z = \frac{X}{\sigma}$.
 Then, for every $t\in\mathbb{R}$, 
$$
\mathbb{E}[e^{it Z}] = \mathbb{E}[e^{i \frac{t}{\sigma} X}]
= e^{i  \frac{t}{\sigma} \mu - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2\left(\frac{t}{\sigma}\right)^2}
= e^{it  \frac{\mu}{\sigma} - \frac{1}{2}t^2}
$$
which is the characteristic function of a random variable distributed as $N(\frac{\mu}{\sigma},1)$, Therefore, $Z\sim N(\frac{\mu}{\sigma},1)$.